# preg_replace with Regex - find number-sequence in URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm a regex-noobie, so sorry for this "simple" question:

I've got an URL like following:

```
http://stellenanzeige.monster.de/COST-ENGINEER-AUTOMOTIVE-m-w-Job-Mainz-Rheinland-Pfalz-Deutschland-146370543.aspx
```

what I'm going to archieve is getting the number-sequence (aka Job-ID) right before the ".aspx" with preg_replace.

I've already figured out that the regex for finding it could be

```
(?!.*-).*(?=\.)
```

Now preg_replace needs the opposite of that regular expression. How can I archieve that? Also worth mentioning:

The URL can have multiple numbers in it. I only need the sequence right before ".aspx". Also, there could be some php attributes behind the ".aspx" like "&mobile=true"

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$re = '/[^-.]+(?=\.aspx)/i'; 
preg_match($re, $input, $matches);
//=> 146370543
```

This will match text not a hyphen and not a dot and that is followed by `.aspx` using a lookahead `(?=\.aspx)`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA3dX8/1)

Comment: Well as good as this code works, an explanation for OP and further readers would  improve your answer

Comment: I've added a brief explanation. Linked demo has lot more details about this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `preg_match` (you don't need `preg_replace`, as you don't want to change the original string) and capture the number before the `.aspx`, which is always at the end, so the simplest way, I could think of is:

```
<?php
$string = "http://stellenanzeige.monster.de/COST-ENGINEER-AUTOMOTIVE-m-w-Job-Mainz-Rheinland-Pfalz-Deutschland-146370543.aspx";
$regex = '/([0-9]+)\.aspx$/';
preg_match($regex, $string, $results);
print $results[1];
?>
```

A short explanation:

`$result` contains an array of results; as the whole string, that is searched for is the complete regex, the first element contains this match, so it would be `146370543.aspx` in this example. The second element contains the group captured by using the parentheeses around `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the opposite by using this regex:

```
(\D*)\d+(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO1yB5/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-100] `http://stellenanzeige.monster.de/COST-ENGINEER-AUTOMOTIVE-m-w-Job-Mainz-Rheinland-Pfalz-Deutschland-`
2.  [109-114]   `.aspx`
```

Even if you just want the number for that url you can use this regex:

```
(\d+)
```

Comment: I've used preg_match instead, but this is the right answer for preg_replace . Thank you!